# Get a unique list (by key) from a list-in-list

Tags: c#

I have a list of requests. Each request has many approvers. I want to go through all the requests and their approvers and get a list of unique approvers and their requests.

Here are sample models:

```
var requestsToProcess = await GetBatchOfApprovedRequestsAsyn(); // new List<RequestModel>();

public class RequestModel
{   
    public RequestModel() 
    {
        ApproversList = new List<RequestApproverModel>();
    }

    public long   Id          { get; set; } // Key
    public string Brief       { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<RequestApproverModel> ApproversList { get; set; }
}

public class RequestApproverModel
{   
    public string Email       { get; set; } // Key
    public string FullName    { get; set; }
}
```

I know how to get unique tuple from a list but don't understand if the target list is on an element of another list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique list of items using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186818/unique-list-of-items-using-linq)

Comment: @Kraego Do you think it does?

Comment: @kraego, for a 0-level list, I already know how to extract my required tuple. But my target list is at depth level 2

Comment: OP: I would suggest that you first flatten the structure (perhaps using `.SelectMany`) such that you have a Approver/Request combination object. Then you can group by the approver to get all requests by their approvers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the premise, is *flatten* and *project*, then *groupby*, then optionally *project* again.

**Given**

```
var requests= new List<RequestModel>()
{
   new()
   {
      Id = 1,
      ApproversList = new List<RequestApproverModel>()
      {
         new(){Email = "bob"},
         new(){Email = "dole"}
      }
   },
   new()
   {
      Id = 2,
      ApproversList = new List<RequestApproverModel>()
      {
         new(){Email = "bob"},
         new(){Email = "blerg"}
      }
   }
};
```

**Example**

```
var results  =requests.SelectMany(request => 
      request.ApproversList, 
      (request, approver) => new {request, approver})
   .GroupBy(x => x.approver.Email )
   .Select(x => new { Approver = x.Key, Requests = x.Select(y => y.request).ToList() });

foreach (var item in results)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Approver);
   foreach (var request in item.Requests)
      Console.WriteLine(" " + request.Id);
}
```

**Output**

```
bob
 1
 2
dole
 1
blerg
 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The two complementary methods you need from LINQ are SelectMany, which unpacks a list-of-lists to a list, and GroupBy, which packs a list to a list-of-lists (you need to go from a-of-b to b-of-a)

```
var result = someRequestModels
  .SelectMany(rm => rm.ApproversList, (rm, ram) => new { RM = rm, RamEmail = ram.Email })
  .GroupBy(at => at.RamEmail, at => at.RM);
```

The SelectMany is like a nested pair of foreach

```
foreach(var rm in someRequestModels)
  foreach(var ram in rm.ApproversList)
    flatlist.Add(new { rm, ram});
```

This has turned the list of lists into a single list, repeating the RequestModel over and over per RequestApproverModel. You can then run a GroupBy of approver Email which takes every unique email in the flattened list and puts together a list of list of RequestModels. In non LINQ pseudocode it'd look something like:

```
foreach(var rmRamPair In flatlist)
  grouping[rmRamPair.Email].Add(rmRamPair.Rm);
```

This produces an IGrouping which is something like a list of lists, where each entry has a Key, a string of the approver's email and is an enumerable of all the requestmodels they have, so eg

```
foreach(var x in result){
  Console.WriteLine($"approver with email of {x.Key} has cases:";

  foreach(var rm in x)
    Console.WriteLine($"id is '{rm.Id}' and Brief is '{rm.Brief}'");

}
```

If it makes you more comfortable, you can call `ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList())` on the result and you'll get a `Dictionary<string, List<RequestModel>>` out, the email being the key and and list of requestmodels being the value

If you want the whole RequestApproverModel, not just the email it might be a bit more tricky. It's easy if you've reused instances of RAM so if there is literally only one object in memory that is "bob@mail.com" and that object is present on a couple of different requests:

```
var ram = new RequestApproverModel{ Email = "bob@mail.com" };

var r1 = new RequestModel();
r1.ApproversList.Add(ram);

var r2 = new RequestModel();
r2.ApproversList.Add(ram);
```

Here the instance is the same one; you can just group by it instead of the email.

If you've ended up with objects that look the same but are at different memory addresses:

```
var r1 = new RequestModel();
r1.ApproversList.Add(new RequestApproverModel{ Email = "bob@mail.com" });

var r2 = new RequestModel();
r2.ApproversList.Add(new RequestApproverModel{ Email = "bob@mail.com" });
```

Then the standard implementation of Equals and GetHashcode(inherited from object) is useless because it's based on the memory stress where the instances live.
Your RequestModel class will instead need to implement Equals and GetHashcode that report equality based on Email, otherwise grouping by the whole RequestModel won't work out